# How to write the toast message inside the edittext onclick listener in android?

Tags: android, toast

I am beginer in android development,

i need to get the toast message after i had enter the text in edittext
i had used the following code:

```
order_dicount_Edit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String dis=order_dicount_Edit.getText().toString();
            int disc=Integer.parseInt(dis);
            if(disc>100)
            {

                Toast.makeText(this, "Discount should be less than 100",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


        }
```

i am getting the error as follows:

```
The method makeText(Context, CharSequence, int) in the type Toast is not applicable for the arguments (new View.OnClickListener(){}, String, int)
```

Comment: in your toast context it should be activity and not the view. change it to YOUR_ACTIVITY.this and it should work

Comment: Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Discount should be less than 100",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: change **this** to **getApplicationContext();**

Answer (score 2):

Change this

```
Toast.makeText(this, "Discount should be less than 100",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

to

```
Toast.makeText(ActivityName.this, "Discount should be less than 100",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

or

```
Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Discount should be less than 100",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

`this` does not refer to a valid context. It refers to `new View.OnClickListener()` which is a annonymous inner class which implements the interface `OnClickListener`.

Also it is better to have a try catch

```
try
{
    int disc=Integer.parseInt(dis);

}catch(NumberFormatException e)
{
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of `this`  use `yourActivity.this` or `getApplicationContext()`

```
order_dicount_Edit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
{
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
       {
             String dis=order_dicount_Edit.getText().toString();
            int disc=Integer.parseInt(dis);
            if(disc>100)
            {
                Toast.makeText( yourActivity.this, "Discount should be less than 100",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "Discount should be less than 100",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
}
```

As `this` always refers to current object, so when you are writting `this` inside the `OnClickListener()` interface it refers to `OnClickListener()` instead of Activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can get same view context where you set onClickListener
like

```
myEditText.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

try implementing **textchange listener** instead of click listener

i am showing you a simple example of it.

```
order_dicount_Edit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            if(order_dicount_Edit.getText().toString().length()>2 && Integer.parseInt(_email.getText().toString())>100){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Discount should be less than 100", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "`this`" in `Toast.makeText(**this**, "Discount should be less than 100",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` write *yourActivityName*.this

Mine worked that way!!